# Programmatically restart Node applications on Plesk

Tags: plesk

We are using Plesk to host our production services.

Basically when I deploy application to Plesk using Git, I need to press `Restart application` within Node page on Plesk GUI and that works well.

But in some cases I need to do that pragmatically, I need to automatically restart Node service. Does Plesk offer such functionality? Maybe, some kind of API that listens to calls or else within Linux shell itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no answer for a while, this is my old workaround that I used for PM2 scripts force reset:

If it's a webserver application, e.g. Express.js, add protected route that can be accessed only within your privatae network (for security reasons) which basically kills main process via `process.exit(0)` and your webserver will get reseted automatically by PM2 or whichever service you use for it. However, I wouldn't recommend this method for anything above staging.

Answer (score 9):

When you click `Restart App` you'll notice a message state `Information: The restart.txt file was touched. Application will be restarted after the first request.`

You can emulate this action after the deploy by checking `Enable additional deploy actions` in the git repository options, and touching the same file here (I also run npm install too). Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: `touch: cannot touch 'tmp/restart': No such file or directory` :(

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue too, and Plesk support don't have an answer for me either.

According to the Plesk blog [here](https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/): "Moreover, if your app is running in the “development” mode, you don’t need to restart the app every time you modify the contents of a file."

I'm very new to Node so I don't fully understand the implications but I guess if you run the app in development mode, then you won't need to manually restart the Node Application.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found that consistently works on Plesk is this command:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Even in development mode, Node does not seem to automatically restart.

What's worse is that it takes about 5-6 seconds before Node finishes restarting, using the touch method.

My takeaway is that a Plesk server is the wrong place to do Node development or testing.

Comment: Hi @dietcheese, do you use this instead of the restart button please?